# Can I create a OneToOneField that will create an object if it does not exist?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working with a Django model that looks like this:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

That is, it has a one-to-one association with the `User` class from Django's `auth` module. This association is not optional; however, thanks to some legacy code and some manual tinkering with the database, there are cases in which a user does *not* have an associated subscription, which means that code like this:

```
sub = user.subscription
```

will throw a `DoesNotExist` exception. However, much of the codebase assumes that every user has an associated `Subscription` object.

Is there a way I could subclass `OneToOneField` such that, if the associated `Subscription` object does not exist in the database, I will create one and return it when `user.subscription` is called, instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to catch the `post_save` signal, creating an object if necessary.

Comment: This mostly happens for legacy (existing) `Users`, so a `post_save` signal is not necessarily fired prior to dereferencing the associated `subscription` object.

Comment: A single query can deal with all the legacy users.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property named `subscription` and in `getter` create necessary reference, for that you may have to do monkey-patching, better alternatives are

1. refactor your code and add a utility function to get subscription
2. refactor your code and add a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for User
3. Just fix the db once